# CSS white-space nowrap not working

Tags: html, css, overflow, whitespace

I have a div with several child divs which are floating left. I don't want them to break, so I set them to `display:inline-block` and `white-space:nowrap`. Unfortunately nothing happens at all. They just keep breaking.

At the end I want to scroll in x-direction, but when I add `overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:visible` it scrolls in y-direction.

```
.a {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
.b {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}

<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

You can see [my complete implementation on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/julian_weinert/88yjz/)

Comment: normally you would put the clearfix on the wrapper div - e.g. if using Nicholas Gallagher's newer micro clearfix hack.

Comment: Clarify. You want the red .a block to have a scrollbar along the bottom when there are too many .b blocks to fit inside?

Comment: @Ruskin: I have a clearfix in my fiddle, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Ruskin You'r right. This is what I wanted. Craighead did solve my problem, see my comment on his answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I may not fully understand your question but it seems like the divs/scroll behave if you remove: `float: left;` from `.b` and add: `overflow:auto;` to `.a`

Comment: Thanks! I changed `.b` to `display:inline-block` and didn't think of the fact, that inline blocks do not break... :)

Comment: In short, `white-space` and `float` are not good friends. Even with `nowrap`, elements if given `float` will ump to new line

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean, but if you stop floading your b, and give your a overflow:auto it should work

see: /jsfiddle.net/88yjz/3/

Comment: Thanks, Craighead had the same fix. I didn't think of the fact, that inline-blocks do not wrap, when I changed `.b` from `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score -1):

Does this give you what you want? Added overflow scroll.

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.a {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:scroll;          /* Added this line*/
    background-color: lightcoral;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.b {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
```